# Add something after all sticky posts in The Loop

Tags: posts, loop, sticky-post

Let's say I've got some posts and some of them are sticky. The sticky posts are displayed at the very top in The Loop.

```
while( have_posts() ) {
  the_post();
  get_template_part();
}
```

How can I add some text after all sticky posts?

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it.

First of all, add a counter before The Loop.

`$my_posts = 0;`

Then in The Loop increment it by one each time.

`$my_posts++;`

Stickies are always at the very top, so compare the number of all sticky posts with current post in The Loop and display custom message.

```
if( $my_posts === count( get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) )
  echo 'this will only appear after all sticky posts';
```

Comment: Or you could use the WP function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_sticky

Comment: @shanebp I've no idea how you could possibly use `is_sticky` in my case... Please add an answer.